# How to update multiple divs while typing (javascript onkeyUp)?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a short javascript code that updates the content of a div element (box1 in the example below). It replaces the default text ("hello") with the text typed in an input element.

I would like to modify this code so it'd update not only the box1 div, but box2 and box3 too. I tried to use getElementsByClassName, but I was unable to make it work. I would be very grateful if somebody'd help me. Thank you.

```
<div class="font1" id="box1">hello</div>
<div class="font2" id="box2">hello</div>
<div class="font3" id="box3">hello</div>
<input type='text' name='fname' class='chatinput' onkeyUp="document.getElementById('box1').innerHTML = this.value" />
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're on the right track. Just use the same command three times, either inline:

```
<input type="text" name="fname" class="chatinput" onkeyUp="
  document.getElementById('box1').innerHTML = this.value;
  document.getElementById('box2').innerHTML = this.value+'hello';
  document.getElementById('box3').innerHTML = this.value+'world';" />
```

or use a JavaScript function:

```
<script>
function clickMe(s){
  document.getElementById("box1").innerHTML = s;
  document.getElementById("box2").innerHTML = s+"hello";
  document.getElementById("box3").innerHTML = s+"world";
}
</script>
<input type="text" name="fname" class="chatinput" onkeyUp="clickMe(this.value)" />
```

(Side note: Use double quotes for HTML-attributes. Even though all browser will understand you if you use single quotes, the double quote is the standard and the only allowed way if you want to be XML/XHTML/HTML5-compatible)

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you :)

```
document.querySelector('.chatinput').onkeydown = function(){
    var box1 = document.querySelector('#box1'),
        box2 = document.querySelector('#box2'),
        box3 = document.querySelector('#box3');

    box1.innerHTML = box2.innerHTML = box3.innerHTML = (this.value);
}
```

You basicly create a `onkeydown` event, and attach it to the `input.chatinput`. I advise you, not to use inline javascript in the HTML

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div class="font1" id="box1">hello</div>
<div class="font2" id="box2">hello</div>
<div class="font3" id="box3">hello</div>
<input type='text' name='fname' class='chatinput' onkeyUp="document.getElementById('box1').innerHTML = this.value; document.getElementById('box2').innerHTML = this.value; document.getElementById('box3').innerHTML = this.value; " />
```

**[Demo Here](https://jsfiddle.net/7q831moa/)**

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByClassName('box')` return list of element so you should do this in a for loop

```js
function onKeyUp($this){
  for(var i in document.getElementsByClassName('box'))
    document.getElementsByClassName('box')[i].innerHTML = $this.value
  }
```

```html
<div id="box1" class="box">hello</div>
<div id="box2" class="box">hello</div>
<div id="box3" class="box">hello</div>
<input type='text' name='fname' class='chatinput' onkeyUp="onKeyUp(this)" />
```

Answer (score 0):

## jQuery:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e426e6cr/)

```
    function foo(value){
        $("div").each(function(){
            this.innerHTML = value;
        })
    };
```

## angular:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gnxmg8oe/)

```
<body ng-app>
    <div class="font1" id="box1">Hello {{value}}</div>
    <div class="font2" id="box2">hi {{value}}</div>
    <div class="font3" id="box3">nihao {{value}}</div>
    <input type='text' name='fname' class='chatinput' ng-model="value" />
</body>
```